# Why DefaultParameterSetName restrain me to input the parameter?

Tags: powershell

```
function CTC {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "LocalBox")]
param
(
    [Alias("l")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "LocalBox", Mandatory)]
    [Switch]
    $Local,

    [Alias("b")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "LocalBox")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "CloudTest")]
    [string]
    $BranchName = "head",

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "CloudTest")]
    [string]
    $Tenant = "bingadsucmaz_cu"
)
process {

    }
}
```

I have a function named "CTC", it has two parameter sets. The first one is "LocalBox" and I set it as default parameter set, the second one is "CloudTest". When I choose to run "CTC" without any parameters, it remind me to input the value like :

> cmdlet CTC at command pipeline position 1
>   Supply values for the following parameters:
>   Local:

But suppose the meaningful action is the cmd choose to run "CloudTest" parameter set, right ?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question. You defined LocalBox parameter set as the default and as such, if you run it without any parameters, that parameter set is going to be used. I don't get why you would use a switch as part of the default because they're usually used to do something that is not the default. You would use `$true` or `$false` as the value. If you call your script manually you'd be able to use `-Local:$false` to set it explicitly.

Comment: Your `Local` parameter is set as `Mandatory`, simply sounds like you don't want this.